# Implementing a P controller

Tags: vhdl

I want to control a motor using a P controller (and a PID later on).
Here is the VHDL code I am using for the P controller:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
USE ieee.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.ALL;

entity P is
    Port ( e : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0);
           PWM : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0));
end P;

architecture Behavioral of P is

signal eInt : integer := 0;
signal PWMInt : integer := 0;

--min/max
signal borne : integer := 255;

--Gain
signal Ku : integer := 1;

--saturation
component saturation is
    Port ( entier : in  integer;
           borne : in  integer;
           sotie : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0));
end component;

begin

    eInt <= conv_integer(e);
    PWMInt <= Ku*eInt;

    sat : saturation port map(PWMInt, borne, PWM);

end Behavioral;
```

where saturation limits the quantity PWM to "borne" (so that PWM is at most 255 in binary), e is the error (command - measurement).

The output of this block is a PWM going directly to a motor (this is done in another file). The open loop works just fine, the closed loop is just awful. I strongly suspect that there is something wrong with the way I handle integers, as the testbench is working fine, but the physical implementation is not right at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be next to impossible to tell what is going on as long as you are using all those arithmetic libraries.

Best approach : get rid of `std_logic_signed`, `std_logic_arith`, and make the ports either `signed` or `unsigned` from numeric_std. `conv_integer` is replaced by `to_integer` from the numeric_std library.

If you can't change the ports, use (e.g.) `signed` throughout the internals and only convert from/to `std_logic_vector` at input/output ports.

I presume you are simulating this loop?

Comment: Thanks! And yes I am simulating it, why?

Comment: I am using numeric_std now. The code is much simpler and I pinned down the error to the "PWInt <= Ku*eInt". Turns out that is you replace Ku by 1 then everything works fine again. Any guess?

Comment: Now start using the type system in your favour... eint and pwmint are not just integers; they have a well defined range, determined by the size of E, PWM. Define a subtype for them... subtype pwm is integer range -256..255;   signal eint : pwm; etc ... when you see these ranges, at some point you will see that the only reasonable value for Ku is 1; unless e has a small range around 0, any other value for Ku will saturate PWM and lose loop control. At which point we need to start thinking about fixed point arithmetic so you can control the gain more finely... next message

Comment: Simplest way of adding fixed point arith for this application: signal Ku : integer := 16; -- implicit, Ku is in sixteenths ... and then PWMInt <= (Ku*eInt) / 16; -- now we have finer control of the gain. As long as the division is by a power of 2, you can trust it to be efficient in hardware!